# mapnik proj4 tpers error

Tags: mapnik, proj

I'm working on a project where we need our tiles rendered with tilt perspective.
I have installed and running openstreetmap server and it's working, but I need this projection to work:

> +proj=tpers +h=500000.000 +lat_0=19 +lon_0=19 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +azi=30
>   +tilt=40 +R=6371000 +units=m

if I insert this in style.xml I get this error from rendered
Unknown projection string, using web mercator as never the less

how can I get the tiles rendered with this projecting string or any other
perspective view

Comment: The height looks low to me. Try using a much larger h value, at least to see if you can get it working.